# Windows and Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a partition. Now I have Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 for dual boot.
I followed [this](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) tutorial to install Ubuntu.
Now when I switch on the computer I have the following options in the grub.

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu (advandced)
- Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)
- System setup

Is this normal? I mean, what is Windows Boot Manager? Should it say just Windows?
Why can I access the BIOS if I select System Setup?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, from my own experiences, yes it is normal for Grub to chain link to the Windows Boot Manager. Basically, it is the boot-loader that starts Windows, like Grub is the boot-loader that starts Ubuntu. The reason it is listed like that is because rather than starting Windows by itself, it chains itself to the Windows boot-loader so it'll do its job.
You can access the BIOS anyways as that's overhead for boot-loaders and any operating system and is on the motherboard, not the hard-drive, where your operating system is from. BIOS stands for Basic Input Output System.

Comment: If I missed any information, didn't explain something properly, or am incorrect about a statement I made, please, let me know! I'll correct myself.

Answer (score 0):

The `System Setup` is just a second name of BIOS setup. When you are in BIOS you see words in the title in there 'BIOS Setup Utility`or`CMOS setup utilty` so it is all the same - BIOS, and it doesn't mean an installation of any OS.

If you don't like names in GRUB menu you can change them, you would need to operate via `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and `update-grub` which will rewrite your  `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (don't modify this file yourself),  but that's another story.